# Trouble loading file WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, save, loading

Hi I am making a simple input data and output data program. Currently I am struggling with the saving and loading. It keeps saying loading has failed.
I have two classes, one for data and another called 'Report Manager' which adds the data to a dictionary. Not sure if I have gone the long winded way about this.

In the class for the data stored about the circuit boards, I have the following constructor:

```
  public board(string inNumber, int inBaudRate1, int inBaudRate2, int inBaudRate3, int inBaudRate4, int inParidy1,int inParidy2, int inParidy3, int inParidy4, int inStopBits1, int inStopBits2, int inStopBits3, 
        int inStopBits4, int inDataBits1, int inDataBits2, int inDataBits3, int inDataBits4, string inPortName1, string inPortName2, string inPortName3, string inPortName4, string inDate)
    {
        inNumber = batchNumber;

        BaudRate1 = inBaudRate1;
        BaudRate2 = inBaudRate2;
        BaudRate3 = inBaudRate3;
        BaudRate4 = inBaudRate4;

        Paridy1 = inParidy1;
        Paridy2 = inParidy2;
        Paridy3 = inParidy3;
        Paridy4 = inParidy4;

        stopBits1 = inStopBits1;
        stopBits2 = inStopBits2;
        stopBits3 = inStopBits3;
        stopBits4 = inStopBits4;

        dataBits1 = inDataBits1;
        dataBits2 = inDataBits2;
        dataBits3 = inDataBits3;
        dataBits4 = inDataBits4;

        portName1 = inPortName1;
        portName2 = inPortName2;
        portName3 = inPortName3;
        portName4 = inPortName4;

        date = inDate;
    }
```

I then have the following save and load methods in the **same** class:

```
   public virtual void Save(System.IO.TextWriter textOut)
    {
            textOut.WriteLine(batchNumber);
            textOut.WriteLine(BaudRate1);
            textOut.WriteLine(BaudRate2);
            textOut.WriteLine(BaudRate3);
            textOut.WriteLine(BaudRate4);
            textOut.WriteLine(Paridy1);
            textOut.WriteLine(Paridy2);
            textOut.WriteLine(Paridy3);
            textOut.WriteLine(Paridy4);
            textOut.WriteLine(stopBits1);
            textOut.WriteLine(stopBits2);
            textOut.WriteLine(stopBits3);
            textOut.WriteLine(stopBits4);
            textOut.WriteLine(dataBits1);
            textOut.WriteLine(dataBits2);
            textOut.WriteLine(dataBits3);
            textOut.WriteLine(dataBits4);
            textOut.WriteLine(portName1);
            textOut.WriteLine(portName2);
            textOut.WriteLine(portName3);
            textOut.WriteLine(portName4);
            textOut.WriteLine(date);
            //method to save the skier
    }



    public bool Save(string filename)
    {
        System.IO.TextWriter textOut = null; //set to null
        try
        {
            textOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename);
            Save(textOut); //call save method
        }
        catch
        {
            return false; //if failed return false
        }
        finally
        {
            if (textOut != null) //if saved
            {
                textOut.Close(); //close file
            }

        }
        return true;
    } //save to file

    public static board Load(System.IO.TextReader textIn)
    {
        {
            string batchNumber = textIn.ReadLine();
            int baudRate1 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int baudRate2 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int baudRate3 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int baudRate4 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int paridy1 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int paridy2 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int paridy3 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int paridy4 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int stopBits1 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int stopBits2 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int stopBits3 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int stopBits4 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int dataBits1 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int dataBits2 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int dataBits3 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            int dataBits4 = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            string portName1 = textIn.ReadLine();
            string portName2 = textIn.ReadLine();
            string portName3 = textIn.ReadLine();
            string portName4 = textIn.ReadLine();
            string date = textIn.ReadLine();
            board result = new board(batchNumber, baudRate1, baudRate2, baudRate3, baudRate4, paridy1, paridy2, paridy3, paridy4, stopBits1, stopBits2, stopBits3, stopBits4, dataBits1, dataBits2, dataBits3,
                dataBits4, portName1, portName2, portName3, portName4, date);
            return result;
        } //load board
    }


    public static board Load(string filename)
    {
        board result;
        System.IO.TextReader textIn = null;
        try
        {
            textIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
            result = Load(textIn);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (textIn != null) textIn.Close();
        }
        return result;
    } //load from file
```

In the Report Manager class I have the following save and load methods:

```
       public void SaveReport(System.IO.TextWriter textOut)
    {
        textOut.WriteLine(reportName);
        textOut.WriteLine(batchNumber);
        textOut.WriteLine(Boards.Count);
        foreach (board a in Boards.Values)
        {
            a.Save(textOut);
        }
    } //save the report

    public void SaveReport(string filename)
    {
        System.IO.TextWriter textOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename);

        try
        {
            SaveReport(textOut);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
           textOut.Close();
        }

    }

    public static reportManager Load(System.IO.TextReader textIn)
    {
        string reportName = textIn.ReadLine();
        reportManager result = new reportManager(reportName);
        batchNumber = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
        int numberOfBoards = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBoards; i++)
        {
            board a = board.Load(textIn);
            string n = a.getBatchNumber();
            Boards.Add(n, a);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static reportManager Load(string filename)
    {
        reportManager result;
        System.IO.TextReader textIn = null;
        try
        {
            textIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
            result = Load(textIn);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (textIn != null) textIn.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And finally in the Main Window xaml.cs file I have the following at the beginning:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StreamReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            reader = new StreamReader("Report.txt");
            reportManager.Load("Report.txt");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Loading Failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
        newReport.SaveReport("Report.txt");
    }
```

and I have the following code when the save button is clicked:

```
      private void saveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int inBaudRate1 = int.Parse(baudRateInput1.Text);
        int inBaudRate2 = int.Parse(baudRateInput2.Text);
        int inBaudRate3 = int.Parse(baudRateInput3.Text);
        int inBaudRate4 = int.Parse(baudRateInput4.Text);

        int inParity1 = int.Parse(parityInput1.Text);
        int inParity2 = int.Parse(parityInput2.Text);
        int inParity3 = int.Parse(parityInput3.Text);
        int inParity4 = int.Parse(parityInput4.Text);

        int inStopBits1 = int.Parse(stopBitsInput1.Text);
        int inStopBits2= int.Parse(stopBitsInput2.Text);
        int inStopBits3 = int.Parse(stopBitsInput3.Text);
        int inStopBits4 = int.Parse(stopBitsInput4.Text);

        int inDataBits1 = int.Parse(dataBitsInput1.Text);
        int inDataBits2 = int.Parse(dataBitsInput2.Text);
        int inDataBits3 = int.Parse(dataBitsInput3.Text);
        int inDataBits4 = int.Parse(dataBitsInput4.Text);

        string inPortName1 = portNameInput1.Text;
        string inPortName2 = portNameInput2.Text;
        string inPortName3 = portNameInput3.Text;
        string inPortName4 = portNameInput4.Text;

        string inDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHMMss");

        try
        {
            board NewBoard = new board(null, inBaudRate1, inBaudRate2, inBaudRate3, inBaudRate4, inParity1, inParity2, inParity3, inParity4, inStopBits1, inStopBits2, inStopBits3, inStopBits4,
               inDataBits1, inDataBits2, inDataBits3, inDataBits4, inPortName1, inPortName2, inPortName3, inPortName4, inDate);
            NewBoard = newReport.AddBoard(inBaudRate1, inBaudRate2, inBaudRate3, inBaudRate4, inParity1, inParity2, inParity3, inParity4, inStopBits1, inStopBits2, inStopBits3, inStopBits4,
               inDataBits1, inDataBits2, inDataBits3, inDataBits4, inPortName1, inPortName2, inPortName3, inPortName4, inDate);
            //noOfDataEntriesTextBox.Text = NewBoard.getBatchNumber().ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Added");
        }
        finally
        {
            clearAllInput();
            newReport.SaveReport("Report.txt");
        }
    }
```

Sorry if this isn't clear, I can provide more code if needed. 
Thanks, Lucy

Comment: You must show more exception text. Only "loading has failed" is not very helpful...

Comment: You need to provide **less** code, not more. Try to boil it down to a [MCVE]. In doing so, you may inadvertently stumble over the solution to the issue yourself.